# Magento 2 - Is there way to setup taxes world wide automatically?

Tags: magento2, tax, taxes

The merchant asks me to **setup taxes automatically** and he wants to sell products in all available countries.

Are there any extensions for this purpose?

How this problem usually solving?

Answer (score 1):

There are paid solutions like taxjar

https://www.taxjar.com/guides/integrations/magento2/

But nothing free. If free you will need to manage yourselves via admin. You can of course write code to auto import / export of rates. But again that's something you will have to manage.

Comment: Did you use taxjar extension? I reviewed it and looks like it sticks to the US-based merchants, am I wrong?

Comment: Using it on UK based merchant

Comment: ok, thanks will take a look at it again.

Comment: Dealing with tax is awful. If you ask too many questions you will get told to consult a local tax expert. Good luck.